# Is Onboard graphics enough for running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, graphics, intel-graphics

I have:

- a laptop with core i3 processor and onboard graphics, 4gb RAM,
- desktop with core2duo processor, onboard graphics, 2gb RAM.

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop currently running windows XP on it. Is configuration enough to run Ubuntu 12.04 on desktop?

Though I can install it on my laptop too but i would prefer to do it on desktop.

Comment: You may have problems with the second machine, if it has rather exotic card embedded, VIA for example. You should have no problems with i3 embedded.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino Desktop has got intel onboard graphics. Intel G33/G31 Express chipset family

Answer (score 1):

No problem installing Ubuntu 12.04 on either your desktop or your laptop. All you need is 384MB of RAM. Installing even a cheap, low-end graphics card on your desktop will noticeably improve your performance.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications that you have mentioned are more than enough to run Ubuntu 12.04.